# How to reduce the size of equation numbers?

Tags: equations, numbering

I am creating a presentation where I have equation numbers.

I decided to show all the numbers to make it easier for the audience to refer to individual equations.

I would like to ask if there is a simple method to make the displayed numbers smaller than normal.

Comment: See the documentation of the `mathtools` package (p.9-10): it has a `\newtagform` command to customise the appearance of equation numbers

Answer (score 2):

To expand the comment of @Bernard,

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{smalleqnum}[\tiny]{\tiny (}{)}
\usetagform{smalleqnum}
```

Solved my problem nicely. Let me also add the link [here.](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf)

Comment: The `\usetagform` instruction can be simplified to `\newtagform{smalleqnum}{\tiny (}{)}`, as the `\tiny` directive is a switch, i.e., its scope doesn't end until the current TeX group ends.